# Guessing the general form of a function

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, dirac-delta

I have a quantity $Q(x,y)$, such that $x \in \{-n \dots n \}$ and $y \in \{ 0 \dots n \}$ where $n \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \dots \}$ is a positive integer. It turns out that

With $n=1$,   $Q(x,y) = 1$ for $(x,y) = (-1,1), (1,0)$.

With $n=2$, $Q(x,y) =1$ for $(x,y) = (-2,2), (0,1), (2,0)$.

With $n=3$, $Q(x,y)=1$ for $(x,y) = (-3,3), (-1,2), (1,1), (3,0)$.

With $n=4$, $Q(x,y)=1$ for $(x,y) = (-4,4), (-2,3), (0,2), (2,1), (4,0)$.

For all other $(x,y)$ for a given $n$ $Q(x,y) =0$.

My question is, can $Q(x,y)$ be written in terms of some compact notation say Dirac delta function, or in some other manner that will summarize above observations?

Comment: It's unusual to use an arrow to denote a range. The arrow is usually used to denote a mapping; conventional notations for such ranges would be $x=1,\ldots,2n+1$ or $x\in\{1,\ldots,2n+1\}$ or $1\le x\le 2n+1$.

Comment: Thanks,@joriki, corrected the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Q(x,y)=\delta_{x,2(n-y)+1}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks, @joriki. There was a correction in my question. The variable $x \in \{-n, \dots, n \}$, instead of $\{ 1, \dots, 2n+1\}$.

Comment: @Rob: Well, you subtracted $n+1$ from $x$, so you get $Q(x,y)=\delta_{x,n-2y}$ instead, right?

Comment: I don't know how you do it so quickly! But it seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rob: The Kronecker delta is $1$ exactly if its two arguments are equal. If you subtract $n+1$ from the one argument, you have to subtract $n+1$ from the other argument as well to get the same result. $2(n-y)+1-(n+1)=n-2y$.